# How to create a virtual audio device

Tags: c#, audio, dll, virtual, device

I am working on a project in C# for which I need to create several virtual audio devices. 
Later I will be doing some switching with them on my own.

Does maybe anyone know a nice library that would allow me to do it problematically on my own. To create instances of audio devices. (commercial is OK, but free .dll would be better)

Another solution, that would be an optional solution, is to find a software that creates virtual audio devices according to my desires.

Comment: I am working on a virtual audio device software that should hopefully be able to be used as an API, shoot me an email at officialtoxicdub@gmail.com and I'll get back to you once it's done

Comment: I like the way @user853710 use problematically. noice

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to create virtual audio devices in C#. You need to create windows device drivers using the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx) in C/C++.

Have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/117625/how-to-create-a-virtual-audio-device-and-stream-audio-input-with-it) for some links to commerical virtual audio devices.

Comment: Well, actually I bought a software called Virtual audio cable for 20 $. works fine. Too bad I can not use it as an API But I will get along. It can produce up to 128 virtual audio devices.

Comment: Thank you for this. I partially solved my problem using VAC. Although, it will be awesome if I can do this problematically